# PHP - Different values with same result

Tags: php

**Whats wrong? :X**
Its impossible to give this difference with same value.

```
echo ceil(0.55*100); //56
echo ceil(55); //55
```

Comment: please check this one `ceil((int)(0.55 * 100))`

Comment: Hi,
Thank you if you help me to solve this.
I need this round up with 2 decimal

    echo round(ceil((0.55*100))/100,2); // output 0.56

0.050 -> 0.05
0.051 -> 0.06
0.055 -> 0.06
0.059 -> 0.06
0.060 -> 0.06

Thank you